# WPF Form must Down

Tags: wpf

WPF form must fall down in the task bar.. But I dont know do that?

+-x

x ---> Close the form
- ---> down the form taskbar?

Comment: the word you're looking for is minimize. Are you asking how to do that in code?

Comment: Yes kate - I exactly want to this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the closing event of the WPF Window to cancel closing and minimize it instead:

XAML:

```
<Window ... Closing="Window_Closing">
```

Code behind:

```
private void Window_Closing(object sender, System.ComponentModel.CancelEventArgs e)
{
  e.Cancel = true;
  this.WindowState = WindowState.Minimized;
}
```

But you have to be aware that this also prevents other ways of closing the window, e.g. Alt+F4, "Close Window" from the toolbar etc.

Comment: Or if you don't want to turn closing into minimizing (it's really hard to tell from your question) just use that line `this.WindowState = WindowState.Minimized; ` wherever you want to make the window minimize.

Answer (score 0):

You may checkout the [WPF NotifyIcon control](http://www.hardcodet.net/projects/wpf-notifyicon).

Comment: That's about minimizing to the system tray. If you want to minimize to the taskbar, it won't help you.